# $\Delta^d m^n =d! \sum_{k} \left[ m \atop k \right] { {k+n} \brace m + d}(-1)^{m+k}$ Is this a new formula?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, stirling-numbers

(EDIT: The variable $z$ is changed to $d$ so as not to be confused with generating function notation)

I have derived this formula involving the Stirling numbers that I now feel confident is correct (at least for non-negative integers $m$, $n$ and $d$).

$$\frac{\Delta^d m^n}{d!} = \sum_{k} \left[ m \atop k \right] { {k+n} \brace m + d}(-1)^{m+k}$$

(where the difference is taken with respect to $m$), giving the specific case for the plain exponent
$$m^n = \sum_{k} \left[ m \atop k \right] { {k+n} \brace m}(-1)^{m+k}$$
I am hoping that someone can provide a nice concise proof, as my proof involves a relatively lengthy path using a two dimensional induction argument just to show the formula for $m^n$. From there a straight application of the difference $$\Delta^d m^n = \Delta^{d-1}(m+1)^n - \Delta^{d-1}m^n$$ along with the identities $$\left[ m+1 \atop k \right] = m\left[ m \atop k\right] + \left[ m \atop k-1\right]$$ and $${ k+n \brace m+d} = { k+n+1 \brace m+d+1}  - ( m+d+1) { k+n \brace m+d+1} $$
leads to the general $d$-th difference formula.

This is in my opinion the nicest formula that I have seen involving both types of Stirling numbers, since it completely eradicates the powers. It is not a transformation from regular powers to falling powers/factorials, so maybe the formula could be used in situations where removing the exponent at the cost of adding the Stirling numbers is convenient.

```
Does anyone care to make an attempt at giving a nice proof (or a reference)?
```

Comment: Notice that this is the inversion formula when $n=0$ and $z=0$, which gives the correct restult of $1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What follows  is a proof that  is assembled from  various pieces which
we'll  link  to  in  order  not to  have  to  repeat  well-established
material.

We seek to evaluate
$$f_n = \sum_{k=1}^m
\left[m\atop k\right] {k+n\brace m} (-1)^{m+k}.$$
Following Wilf, we introduce the generating function
$$f(z) = \sum_{n\ge 0} f_n z^n.$$
We will have succeeded if we can show that
$$f(z) = \frac{1}{1-mz}$$
since $$[z^n] \frac{1}{1-mz} = m^n.$$

Observe that
$$f(z) = \sum_{n\ge 0} z^n \sum_{k=1}^m
\left[m\atop k\right] {k+n\brace m} (-1)^{m+k}
= \sum_{k=1}^m
\left[m\atop k\right] (-1)^{m+k}
\sum_{n\ge 0} {k+n\brace m} z^n.$$

We will do  the inner sum first. Recall  that the bivariate generating
function of the Stirling numbers of the second kind is given by
$$G(z, u) = \exp\left(u (\exp(z)-1)\right).$$
This implies for the sum that
$$\sum_{n\ge 0} {k+n\brace m} z^n
= \sum_{n\ge 0} z^n (k+n)! [z^{n+k}] \frac{1}{m!} (\exp(z)-1)^m.$$

Note that  the part after  the coefficient extraction operator  is the
generating function
$$\sum_{q\ge m} {q\brace m}\frac{z^q}{q!}.$$

Now this  is the  moment where we  need a subtle  observation concerning
generating functions.  If we  extract the coefficient $[z^{n+k}]$ from
an exponential generating function and  multiply by $(k+n)!$ we get the
value generated  by the EGF at  $k+n$. If we then  multiply by $z^n$
and sum over all $n$ we  get the ordinary generating function of these
values divided by $z^k.$ (Note that the exp term starts at $z$ and $m\ge k$
so it is safe to divide by $z^k.$ Furthermore we start extracting coefficients at $k$ and $k\le m$ so we can be sure that we get all of them.) 
This is a bit of a cognitive  leap but by no
means voodoo  of any sort. We  have simply observed  how a coefficient
extraction operator combined with a  summation can turn an EGF into an
OGF.

This OGF is well known however and is calculated e.g. at this [MSE link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/422006/generating-function-with-stirlings-numbers-of-the-second-kind). It is given by
$$z^m \prod_{q=1}^m \frac{1}{1-qz}.$$

Returning to $f(z)$ we thus obtain
$$f(z) = \sum_{k=1}^m
\left[m\atop k\right] (-1)^{m+k}
\frac{z^m}{z^k} \prod_{q=1}^m \frac{1}{1-qz}.$$
Moving parts that do not depend on $k$ to the front we get
$$(-1)^m z^m \times \prod_{q=1}^m \frac{1}{1-qz}
\times \sum_{k=1}^m
\left[m\atop k\right] \frac{(-1)^k}{z^k}.$$

Now note that the remaining sum is the ordinary generating function of
$\left[m\atop k\right]$ with respect  to $k$ evaluated at $-1/z.$ This
generating function is given by 
(consult e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind))
$$\prod_{q=0}^{m-1} (x+q).$$

This gives for our sum
$$(-1)^m z^m \times \prod_{q=1}^m \frac{1}{1-qz}
\times \prod_{q=0}^{m-1} \left(-\frac{1}{z}+q\right)
= (-1)^m \times \prod_{q=1}^m \frac{1}{1-qz}
\times \prod_{q=0}^{m-1} \left(-1+qz\right)
\\ = \prod_{q=1}^m \frac{1}{1-qz}
\times \prod_{q=0}^{m-1} \left(1-qz\right)
\\ = \frac{1}{1-mz}$$
and we are done. Very nice identity indeed.

Comment: Quite cool and interesting (+1). It may take me some time to feel like I fully understand your answer though (after studying more with generating functions of Stirling numbers). I will add later the path which led me to the formula, it was a fun one.

Comment: I have posted more details on the [MO Question](http://mathoverflow.net/q/161830/26978)

Answer (score 1):

I have found a simple induction argument. For convenience let us introduce notation for the sum when $d=0$ by definition as
$$ \Theta_m^n = \sum_k \left[ m \atop k \right]{k+n \brace m} (-1)^{m+k}$$

The following will validate the recurrence
$$ m \Theta_m^n = \Theta_m^{n+1} + \sum_k \left[ {m+1} \atop k \right]{ k+n \brace m}(-1)^{m+k}$$
so that what will remain in order to prove $\Theta_m^n = m^n$ is to show the second sum is zero. (Note that $\Theta_m^0 = 1$ is true by the inversion formula which will complete the induction.)

Use the identity for the Stirling numbers of the first kind
$$ m\left[ m \atop k\right] = \left[ {m+1} \atop m\right] - \left[ m \atop {k-1}\right]$$
and we see that
$$
\begin{align}
m\Theta_m^n &= \sum_k \left[ {m+1} \atop k \right]{ k+n \brace m}(-1)^{m+k} -  \sum_k \left[ m \atop k-1 \right]{ k+n \brace m}(-1)^{m+k} \\
&= \sum_k \left[ {m+1} \atop k \right]{ k+n \brace m}(-1)^{m+k} -  \sum_k \left[ m \atop k \right]{ k+n+1 \brace m}(-1)^{m+k+1} \tag{1}\\
&= \sum_k \left[ {m+1} \atop k \right]{ k+n \brace m}(-1)^{m+k} +  \sum_k \left[ m \atop k \right]{ k+n+1 \brace m}(-1)^{m+k}\\
&= \sum_k \left[ {m+1} \atop k \right]{ k+n \brace m}(-1)^{m+k} +  \Theta_m^{n+1} \\
\end{align}$$

Can the sum be shown to be zero? I thought it was easy but not quite. See my other [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/730766/43193)
$$\sum_k \left[ {m+1} \atop k \right]{ k \brace m}(-1)^{m+k} = 0$$
The case $n=0$ is easy since
the only non-zero terms for this are when $k=m$ and $k=m+1$
$$\left[ m+1 \atop m\right] { m \brace m} - \left[ m+1 \atop m+1\right] { m+1 \brace m} = \left[ m+1 \atop m\right] \cdot 1 - 1\cdot  { m+1 \brace m}$$
This is zero since it is well known that
$$\left[ m+1 \atop m\right]  = { m+1 \brace m}$$

Answer (score 0):

Consult the book Concrete Mathematics, Ronald L. Graham (Author), Donald E. Knuth (Author), Oren Patashnik (Author)

I'm almost certain that this or a very similar identity was in that book. They will not only prove but show how it is related to 15-thousand other identities you didn't think could possibly be proven! (it's a difficult and good read by the way... everyone should take some time to learn from that book IMAO)

Comment: I should have mentioned I am reading the book right now, and have not seen the identity. It has a fairly similar one $\sum_{k} \left[ n \atop k\right] { k \brace m } = {n \choose m}(n-1)^\underline{n-m}$ on page 265. I would be interested in an actual proof as opposed to "probably there is a proof/could be done". Good book though, yes.