# Stirling number of Second kind generating function

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification, recurrence-relations, stirling-numbers

I would like to prove that: $$f_m(x) = \dfrac{x^m}{(1-x)(1-2x)...(1-mx)}$$

Where $$f_m(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} S(n,m)x^n$$  and $S(n,m)$ is stirling number of 2nd kind

Multiplying the recurrence relation $S(n,m) = S(n-1,m-1) + m*S(n-1,m) $ by $x^n$ and simplifying (skipping some steps) I get:

$$f_m(x) = \dfrac{x}{1-mx}f_{m-1}(x)$$
The next step is what I am not sure of:
$$f_m(x)= (\dfrac{x}{1-mx})^m$$

$$ f_m(x) = \dfrac{x^m}{(1-x)(1-2x)...(1-mx)}$$

Is this correct? Or am I completely wrong?

Comment: There are two proofs at this [MSE link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/422006/) including a nice combinatorial one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re right to have doubts about that step: $f_{m-1}(x)$ isn’t $\left(\frac{x}{1-mx}\right)^{m-1}$, so from

$$f_m(x)=\frac{x}{1-mx}f_{m-1}(x)\tag{1}$$

you cannot conclude that

$$f_m(x)=\left(\frac{x}{1-mx}\right)^m\;.$$

(Note that this also doesn’t give you what you want. However, if you assume as an induction hypothesis that

$$f_{m-1}(x)=\prod_{k=1}^{m-1}\frac{x}{1-kx}\;,$$

then $(1)$ would let you conclude that

$$f_m(x)=\prod_{k=1}^m\frac{x}{1-kx}=\frac{x^m}{(1-x)(1-2x)\ldots(1-mx)}\;.$$

Comment: @Sabih: Yes, since you know that $f_1(x)=\frac{x}{1-x}$ to get the induction started.

Answer (score -1):

Alternately, you can use the identity that 
$$S(n, k) = \frac{1}{k!}\sum_{j=0}^{k} (-1)^{k-j} \binom{k}{j} j^n.$$ 
Then is you apply the *Norlund-Rice integral* formula referenced [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%B8rlund%E2%80%93Rice_integral), you can obtain this generating function by residue calculus.

Comment: I think your answer would be greatly improved by filling in the details with respect to residue calculus.