# Show that the number of ways of splitting a set with $n$ elements into $k$ non-empty subsets is equal to $x^n$'s coefficient in a series

Tags: discrete-mathematics, generating-functions, set-partition, stirling-numbers

The series evaluates to (could not put it in the title): $$\frac{x^{k}}{(1-x)(1-2x)...(1-kx)}$$ I tried to come up with something. A solution would probably require a use of the geometric series formula as well as Cauchy's product. The task also demands one to deduce the following formula for the Stirling numbers of the second kind:

$$S(n, 3) = \frac{3^{n-1} - 2^{n} + 1}{2}$$ which does show up as a coefficient after multiplying: $$({\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}x^{n}})({\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}(2x)^{n}})({\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}(3x)^{n}}).$$ I guess I should be able to follow from there, yet I am stuck.

Edit: Thank you for the link as well as the proof. Is it possible to proceed from my suggestion about using the geometric series formula?

Comment: What is meant by an "arrangement"?

Comment: Constructing, partitioning.

Comment: Please give some examples.  I still don't know what you mean.

Comment: From a set $A = ${1, 2, 3} you can create subsets of k elements. If you set $k = 2$, then the goal is to find the number of ways of splitting $A$ into $2$ non-empty subsets.

Comment: I have just edited the title to make it more clear, as it was admittedly confusing.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/422006/generating-function-with-stirlings-numbers-of-the-second-kind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $S(n,k)$  be the number of partitions requested.  Let $R(n,k)$ denote the coefficient of $x^n$ in the given series $F_k(x)$. Clearly $S(0,0)=1= R(0,0)$ and for $n,k>0$ we have $S(n,0)=0=R(n,0)$ and $S(0,k)=0=R(0,k)$. One way to generate a partition of
$\{1,...,n+1\}$ into $k$ nonempty sets is to make $\{n+1\}$ a singleton and   partition   $\{1,...,n\}$ into $k-1$ nonempty sets. The only other way is to start with partition of $\{1,...,n\}$ into $k$ nonempty sets, and adjoin $n+1$ to one of these $k$ sets.  This gives the recurrence formula $$S(n+1,k)=S(n,k-1)+kS(n,k) \,. \quad (*)$$
On the other hand
$$F_k(x)=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} k^{j-1}x^j F_{k-1}(x)$$
implies that
$$R(n,k)=\sum_{j=1}^{n+1-k} k^{j-1}R(n-j,k-1) \,. \; \quad (**)$$
Writing $i=j+1$ we have
$$R(n,k-1)+kR(n,k)=R(n,k-1)+\sum_{i=2}^{n+2-k} k^{i-1}R(n+1-i,k-1) =R(n+1,k)\,,$$
where the rightmost equality follows from (**) with $n$ replaced by $n+1$.
Comparing this to (*) we conclude by induction on $n$ that $R(n,k)=S(n,k)$ for all $n,k$.

Comment: Is there a way, though, to proceed further with my suggestion about using those geometric series?

Comment: Yes- note that the formula for $F_k$ uses this geometric series.

Comment: Having read this attentively I thank you for the proof! It really is impressive. While I was searching for one on this equality, those other were quite long in comparison and not as neat.

Comment: By the way, shouldn’t the sum in the formula for F be infinite? Also, I have realized I do not see how F with $x^j$ was replaced with R(n - j, k - 1) in **.

Comment: Yes, the sum in the formula for $F$ is infinite, corrected. In (**) collect the total contribution to the coefficient of $x^n$.